# php: test if https version of the site exists?

Tags: php

The goal is to test if the https version of the site exists:

ex: http://www.exemple.com: does https://www.exemple.com exist ?

I tried with:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.exemple.com';
print_r(get_headers($url));
?>
```

But this takes 30 seconds to send back an error.
Is there a very quicker way to test it https exists for a domain name ?

Comment: Use CURL or fopen wrapper with a smaller timeout?

Comment: @AghaUmairAhmed - if you read carefully, you'll see that it's **remote** site in question, not local one.